# How to store and split a list of URLs

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to send a list of URLs to a form -> save in a db -> read from the db and display on a page.

So, I generate the list as below using new line (PHP_EOL).

```
foreach ( $filenames as $filename ) {
    $uri .= trailingslashit( IPFS_URL ) . trailingslashit( $ipfs_file_cid ) . $filename . PHP_EOL;
}

<input type="hidden" id="uri" name="uri" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $uri ); ?>" />
```

The input value is stored in a MySQL database via WP `update_post_meta` function. I tried reading the value from db via `preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $post_meta['uri'][0]);` but I can't seem to detect the new line.

What is the best way to store and split the URLs into an array? I thought of using commas but the URL may have a comma in the filename like `https://example.com/my,image.png` (user-uploaded file).

Comment: Try to use `update_post_meta` with provided array from the backend, it should serialize your URL's array and store it in DB.

Comment: The best way would probably be to store your individual URLs into an array, and then encode that as JSON, for output into the HTML code. (Since JSON uses double quotes, you will either have to put your attribute value into single quotes, or escape all the double quotes in the JSON with `&quot;`, the latter a job `htmlspecialchars` can do for you.) And then on the client side, you simply read this JSON string, and parse it ... That removes all concerns about what part of the data, or separator characters, you would need to handle yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that creating hidden inputs, only to have them sent back to the server, is the best way.
If the data is already available on the server in some format, and doesn't need to be modified in the user interface, perhaps you can save directly to the database, without having to process the GET or POST data from an HTML form.

However, if you do have a good reason for using a form, you can use form elements as arrays:

```
foreach ( $filenames as $index => $filename ) {
    $uri = trailingslashit( IPFS_URL ) . trailingslashit( $ipfs_file_cid ) . $filename;
    echo sprintf(
        '<input type="hidden" id="uri_%s" name="uri[]" value="%s" />',
        $index,
        esc_attr( $uri )
    );
}
```

Then `$_POST['uri']` or `$_GET['uri']` will be an array.

As @alexey-novikov pointed out above, `update_post_meta(…)` should serialize an array value, for storage in the database.